# Access A Referenced Node's Fields - Field Level Templating

Tags: theming, entities

I have a content type with a reference field to another content type. This allows an unlimited amount of entries.

I've created a template for this field:
`field--node--field-my-fields.html.twig`

I want to be able to access the fields of my referenced node. Usually you can do this by accessing the entity, but I can't seem to do this.

```
{% for item in items %}
  {{ kint(item.content) }}
{% endfor %}
```

I feel like this should be really simple, but I just can't find a way to get access to the fields!

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: What is being output in kint()?

Comment: @JamieHollern - I can't really say or paste anything here, my browser dies if I try and expand any of the output.

Comment: Could you try to use dump() instead and format that and stick it in a dump somewhere then link to it here?

Comment: `item.entity.body` perhaps?

Comment: @JamieHollern I can't event `dump()` `item.content` out. I'll try `item.entity` now.

Comment: @Clive `item.entity` returns null.

Comment: Better to start with `item`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `item.content` is a render array and usually you can access a referenced entity in a '#' key (for most display settings):

```
{{ item.content['#node'].field_name.value }}
```

**Field Object**

Another way to get the field values is using the field object in `element['#items']` and loop through the FieldItemList:

```
{% for item in element['#items'] %}
    {{ item.entity.field_name.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Then you are independent from the display settings of the field.

For background information see this blog post from Berdir https://www.md-systems.ch/blog/techblog/2017/02/20/twig-and-entity-field-api-or-how-to-take-control-of-nodehtmltwig for the difference between formatted output and the underlying objects. In a field template you don't need to go back to the parent node object, because you can access directly the field object. You can get the parent node from `element['#object']` though, if you want to access other fields.

Comment: `item.content['#node'].title.value` seems to return null, along with any other field.

Comment: `kint(item.content['#node'])` returns null. I've double checked that I've actually got referenced content too!

Comment: Have you configured the display settings of the field to render the entity?. If you only display a label then drupal might not even include the node entity, because it is not needed for that.

Comment: @DanielDewhurst, I added some more information about the field template.

Answer (score 0):

Using preprocess function on MYTHEME.theme file you can :

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
  ...
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $title  = $element['#object']->getTitle();
  $variables['title']['#markup'] = $title;
  ...
}
```

At this point, in field.twig you have the `{{ title }}` variable

Answer (score 0):

If you require to Access A Referenced Node's title in fields twig template
just do this

```
{{ item.content['#node'].title.value }}
```

for the images it is better go for Twig tweak snippets
like i did:

```
{% set public_url = item.content['#node'].field_image[0]|file_uri %}
{{ drupal_image(public_url,'', {alt: 'Promo Event image'|t, title: ''|t}) }}
```