# How to access a custom field in a field twig loop?

Tags: 8, theming, entities

I have a content type article which have a field repeatable "related content"

I use a field twig where I have this  loop

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{ item.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

It works very well : it displays title of the article and a link to the content.

I would like also to display some subfields associated with this content but I'm not successful.

I’ve tried things like  :

```
{{ item.content.field_date_mise_a_jour_article.value }}
```

but obviously it doesn’t work. `item.content` only contains url and title.

How can I do that ?

In `node--article.html.twig`, i can access the related content subfield like that :

```
{{ node.field_suggestion_articles.entity.field_date_mise_a_jour_article.value }}
```

How can I do the same in

```
field--field-suggestion-articles.html.twig
```

Comment: You can user preprocess functions for this and write your code in hook_preprocess_field and there you can create a custom variable to be used in field twig. Did your try this ?

Comment: @MohitWadhwa No, i didn’t try (I was hoping to access custom fields directly in twig template.) but i’ve seen some topics here on this approach. I will try. Maybe you have some code to start ?

Comment: You can access the node in a field twig as well, `{% set node = element['#object'] %}`, and use the node the same way as in a node template.

Comment: @4k4 How do you do ? I've also found your answer here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/233977/access-a-referenced-nodes-fields-field-level-templating#answer-233992 which helps me with `{{ item.content['#node'].field_name.value }}`

Comment: This is not recommended as explained in the linked answer. So better use the node object from the last comment (to get all fields of the parent node) or `element['#items']` for the field object of the current field template.

Comment: BTW digging too deep in the template variables is a sign that you need a custom view mode of the referenced entity. Then you can configure the fields in UI and if still necessary theme a view mode specific template (use Twig debug to find this out).

Comment: @4k4 You mean create view in UI ?My first try was to create a view (in a block) in order to display all the related content of the curent article. Its was easy to display the fields i needed but didn’t achieve to use the contextual filter to only show the related content. That’s an other question and i will try this option.

Comment: No, a display mode (aka view mode), like `teaser` for the front page, you can add for example `related` (go to  /admin/structure/display-modes/view). Then use the template `node--article--related.html.twig` to output the fields.

Comment: @4k4 I’ve done what you advise (create a view mode) based on that answer. It works well and it is a better solution (using fields in the View create some issues) but I’m facing the same issue when I wan to style all the fields.

Comment: @4k4 In view mode "Related Content", we have the field "Related Articles" and not title, image, summary, etc. Since the "Related Articles" field is repeatable, i have `{{ content.field_suggestion_articles }}` in `node--article--related-content.html.twig`. In `field--node--field-suggestion-articles--article.html.twig`, i have `{% for item in items %}{{ item.content }}{% endfor %}`So I can’t access properly to custom fields. I can do something but with ugly code based on https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208723/iterate-through-multiple-value-content-field-in-twig-template

Answer (score 1):

As you are creating the twig template for a field and try to access the fields / data that is not available, you can write your custom code in preprocess function and you should use the [template_preproces_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_field/8.2.x) and create custom variable with desired data and use that variable in custom twig template.

In preprocess function

```
$variables['myVariable'] = 'My Desired Data';
```

In Twig use the variable which will print 'My Desired Data'

```
{{ myVariable }}
```