# Display paragraph field value in field.html.twig - Paragraphs module

Tags: paragraphs

I need to display a field value available to `paragraph.html.twig` in `field.html.twig`.
I have a paragraph type called `buttoncontainer` with a field name called `field_background_color`. I have a paragraph type called `button` nested within that as per the attached screenshot. I need to make the `field_background_color` value available to `field.html.twig`.

Let's say `field_background_color` equates to `#333333`

In `field.html.twig` I want to do something like:

```
<div style="background: {{ color }};">
    {% for item in items %}
        {{ item.content }} 
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Is this something that can be done with a preprocess function?

I tried

```
function mysubtheme_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables) {

  $paragraph = $variables['paragraph'];

  if ($paragraph->getType() === 'sidebar_button_repeater') {
    if (!$paragraph->field_background_color->isEmpty()) {
      $variables['color'] = $paragraph->get('field_background_color')->first()->getValue();
    }
  }
}
```

...but it won't output the value in `field.html.twig`. The goal is simply to allow the user to determine the div background color behind the buttons they create.

Update:
I also added:

```
 {% set paragraph_parent = paragraph.getParentEntity() %}
{% set color = paragraph_parent.field_background_color.0.value %}
Color  is {{ color }}.
```

...but that doesn't work in `field.html.twig` either. It does however work in `paragraph.html.twig` templates.

I found a very useful link at [Access A Referenced Node's Fields - Field Level Templating](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/233977/access-a-referenced-nodes-fields-field-level-templating#answer-233992)  that may inform a change to the code. Maybe syntax using `item`? I can return the NESTED paragraph field values using `{{ item.content['#node'].field_background_color.value }}` but I can't return the PARENT paragraph field value.

My specific version of `field.html.twig` file is `field--paragraph--sidebar-button-repeater.html.twig` and `{{ item.content }}` does natively output the parent field `field_background_color` value (see img). The problem is how to capture that specific value so I can use it in a situation like: `<div style="background: [output from field_background_color ];">` in `field--paragraph--sidebar-button-repeater.html.twig`. I was hoping some iteration of `{{ item.content['#node'].field_background_color.value }}` would achieve it. Can some parent parameter be added to capture the field value?

Here's my `field--paragraph--sidebar-button-repeater.html.twig` code. With the preprocessor function above in mind am I missing anything in `set` to output `{{ color }}`

```
Color is {{ color }} 

    {% for item in items %}
        {{ item.content }}
    {% endfor %}
```

This works for me but may not be the cleanest way:

```
{% set bgcolor = "" %}
{% for item in element['#items'] %}
    {% set bgcolor = item.entity.field_background_color.value %}
{% endfor %} 
   


{% if bgcolor == "#d25d12" %}
<div style="background:#d25d12;">
{% for item in items %}
       {{ item.content }}
    {% endfor %}
<div>
{% endif %}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To have a variable in a field template you need a field preprocess hook:

```
use Drupal\paragraphs\ParagraphInterface;

function mysubtheme_preprocess_field(&$variables) {

  $paragraph = $variables['element']['#object'];
  if ($paragraph instanceof ParagraphInterface) {
    if ($paragraph->getType() === 'sidebar_button_repeater') {
      if (!$paragraph->field_background_color->isEmpty()) {
        $variables['color'] = $paragraph->get('field_background_color')->value;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

## Nested Paragraphs

If the field is in the parent paragraph of a nested paragraph:

```
$parent = $paragraph->getParentEntity();
```

And get the field value from $parent:

```
function mysubtheme_preprocess_field(&$variables) {

  $paragraph = $variables['element']['#object'];
  if ($paragraph instanceof ParagraphInterface) {
    if ($paragraph->getType() === 'child_type') {
      $parent = $paragraph->getParentEntity();
      if ($parent instanceof ParagraphInterface) {     
        if ($parent->getType() === 'parent_type') {
          if (!$parent->field_background_color->isEmpty()) {
            $variables['color'] = $parent->get('field_background_color')->value;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

## Why instanceof?

In the comments it was asked why to use `instanceof`?

In older Drupal versions you would use:

```
$entity_type = $variables['element']['#entity_type'];
$bundle = $variables['element']['#bundle']; 
if ($entity_type === 'paragraph' && $bundle === 'my_bundle') {
  // This works but your IDE doesn't understand it:
  $parent = $paragraph->getParentEntity();
  ...
}
```

In OOP code:

```
if ($paragraph instanceof ParagraphInterface) {
  if ($paragraph->getType() === 'my_bundle') {
    $parent = $paragraph->getParentEntity();
    ...
  }
}
```

Now it's safe to use methods defined in ParagraphInterface. The IDE will help you with autocomplete and by marking unknown methods causing run-time errors.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I added your preprocess function. So specifically in `field.html.twig` type templates (e.g `field--paragraph--sidebar-button-repeater.html.twig`  ).  do I just add `{{ color }}` to return the color e.g. Color is {{ color }}? That didn't work for me unfortunately. Also `$parent = $paragraph->getParentEntity();` doesn't work for me in `field.html.twig`. It just works in `paragraph.html.twig` type templates. This link may lead to a solution: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/233977/access-a-referenced-nodes-fields-field-level-templating#answer-233992. Question edited.

Comment: I've added a complete code example for the parent paragraph.

Comment: Thanks again. I must be overlooking something stupid my end. It just won't output the value for {{ color }} in `field.html.twig` or in `paragraph.html.twig` for that matter. I'll study it harder my end. I must be missing some setting. I appreciate the help! Using Drupal 9.5.10 if that applies.

Comment: My specific version of `field.html.twig` file is `field--paragraph--sidebar-button-repeater.html.twig` and `{{ item.content }}` does natively output the parent field `field_background_color` value. The problem is how to capture that specific value so I can use it in a situation like: `<div style="background: [output from field_background_color ];">` in `field--paragraph--sidebar-button-repeater.html.twig`. I was hoping some iteration of `{{ item.content['#node'].field_background_color.value }}` would achieve it. Can some `parent` parameter be added to capture the field value?

Comment: If you test my code take baby steps. The first code line gets the entity where the field is placed. If it is a paragraph, it gets you to the second line. Put the result of the third line in a variable `$variables['child_type'] = $paragraph->getType()` and output it in the field template {{ child_type }} and so on ...

Comment: Thanks I will study that tonight. For now I have a dirty solution using `item.entity.field_background_color.value` which I will post in the q. I appreciate your help and patience. :)

Comment: My parent paragraph type is `sidebar_button_repeater` and child paragraph type is `sidebar_button`. I'm outputting 3 buttons. In your code do I switch out the `child_type` and `parent_type` for `sidebar_button_repeater` and `sidebar_button` resp? If I have done the above right and added your code to `mysubtheme.theme` file in Drupal, shouldn't adding `{{ color }}` in `field.html.twig`  output my hexcode? I use a List (text) for `field_background_color` where a user picks a hexcode from a select dropdown. I'm very new to Drupal. Thanks

Comment: Isn't child and parent not the other way? You better start debugging by putting more variables in the template as mentioned before.

Comment: No child and parent is right in my logic :) I have another preprocess function that displays fine to paragraph.html.twig but it won't display on field.html.twig. U can see it at https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/2881460. Maybe it's something with the Barrio theme I use: https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_barrio Thanks!

Comment: Weird `$variables['child_type'] = $paragraph->getType();` doesn't display using `{{ child_type }}` and I also don't get any output for `{{ paragraph }}`. Wondering am I missing a module or if functionality is disabled.

Comment: Last q. Can you recommend any good resources about coding preprocess functions for paragraphs. There's nothing on `Drupal\paragraphs\ParagraphInterface` or `instanceof ParagraphInterface` that I'm aware of. Wondering how beginners learn to code this stuff. Thanks